# Why are HTTP image URLs not working with Firebase iOS push notifications?

Tags: ios, https, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have added following option in JSON playload for iOS push notifications and it successfully shows notifications with image using **Notification Service Extension**.

```
"fcm_options": {
  "image": "url-to-image"
}
```

However, when the image URL is `HTTP` and not `HTTPs`, it does not populate the image in notification bar. That image is loaded successfully in `UIImageView` of content detail page inside App.

Here is my implementation inside:

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, 
                             withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)
{
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

    if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {

        // 1. Modify the notification content here...
        bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title)"
        bestAttemptContent.body = "\(bestAttemptContent.body)"

        // 2. Modify badge count
        if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.myBundleId") {

            let badgeCount = userDefaults.integer(forKey: "badgeCount")

            if badgeCount > 0 {
                userDefaults.set(badgeCount + 1, forKey: "badgeCount")
                bestAttemptContent.badge = badgeCount + 1 as NSNumber
            } else {
                userDefaults.set(1, forKey: "badgeCount")
                bestAttemptContent.badge = 1
            }
        }

        // 3. Load image

        /* NOTE: Instead of completing the callback with 
                 self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);,
                 complete it with FIRMessaging extensionHelper */

        //contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)

        Messaging.serviceExtension().populateNotificationContent(bestAttemptContent, 
                                                                 withContentHandler: contentHandler)
    }
}
```

What should I do? Is it necessary to supply image URLs with `HTTPs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a an app with rich push notifications a long time ago, and this is the tutorial I used for that
https://medium.com/@lucasgoesvalle/custom-push-notification-with-image-and-interactions-on-ios-swift-4-ffdbde1f457

I hope it is as helpful to you as it was for me.

Comment: Adding `App Transport Security Settings` and setting `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to YES seems to be working..